# Derivative of $\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{5}{4s^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $r=\dfrac{1}{2s}-\dfrac{5}{4s^3}$

$r=\dfrac{1}{2}s^{-1}-\dfrac{5}{4}s^{-3}$

$r^{\prime}=-\dfrac{1}{2}s^{-2}-\dfrac{5}{4}(-3)s^{-4}$

$r^{\prime}=-\dfrac{1}{2s^{2}}+\dfrac{15}{4s^{4}}$

Is this correct? Because I solved it again a different way by using the quotient rule and I got a different answer. Why wouldn't you use the quotient rule here if there are fractions? I found a common denominator and then used the quotient rule and got a different answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. It's possible that your other answer was equivalent to this one

Comment: Will you edit your question to include what you got using the quotient rule, so that we can compare?

Comment: Wolfram alpha agrees with your answer: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+1%2F%282s%29%E2%88%925%2F%284s^3%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a common denominator and using the quotient rule we have

$$r=\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{5}{4s^3}$$

$$r=\frac{2s^2-5}{4s^3}$$

$$r'=\frac{4s^3\cdot4s-(2s^2-5)\cdot12s^2}{16s^6}=\frac{16s^4-(24s^4-60s^2)}{16s^6}=\frac{60s^2-8s^4}{16s^6}$$

$$r'=-\frac{1}{2s^2}+\frac{15}{4s^4}$$

As you calculated.

Comment: OK, thanks +1 :)